# Генератор рандомных класов для блоков Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress-плагины, wordpress

Мне нужна помощь. Я создаю кастомные блоки для темы и мне нужно чтобы каждый имел какой-то уникальный класс. Как это сделать? Может в вордпресс есть какая-то подобная функция или можно просто сгенерировать случайный набор букв и цифр?

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В PHP есть встроенная функция [uniqid()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).

```
$unique_class_name = str_replace( '.', '-', uniqid( 'class-prefix-', true ) );
```

Получите что-то вроде `class-prefix-4b340550242239-64159797`.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно использовать это:

```
function custom_class($class) {
    $arr_en = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
    $i_ = rand(5, 10);

    for ($i=0; $i < $i_; $i++) { 
       $class .= $arr_en[rand(0, count($arr_en)-1)];        
    }

    return $arr_en;
}
```